# Java: altering locale formatting

Tags: java, format, locale

I would like to modify the way my application locale formats and displays numbers.
In my case the locale is "it_IT", so numbers are formatted with '.' as GroupingSeparator and ',' as DecimalSeparator. Is it possible to alter or remove those symbols at global application level?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what do you want there a different ways. See some below...
**1** set the default locale in your application`Locale.setDefault(Locale.UK);` this will use a comma as GroupingSeparator and a point as DecimalSeparator
**2** you can create the java.text.NumberFormat for a specific locale `NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.UK)`, will behave like solution **1**)
**3** you can use one of the above an remove the GroupingSeparator

```
NumberFormat formatUK = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.UK);
formatUK.setGroupingUsed(false);
```

edit:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberFormat formatUK = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.UK);
        double someValue = 1234567.8899;
        System.out.printf("%16s: %15s%n", "with grouping", formatUK.format(someValue));
        formatUK.setGroupingUsed(false);
        System.out.printf("%16s: %15s%n", "without grouping", formatUK.format(someValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, switching locale works, but I can't manage to disable the GroupingSeparator. Besides, changes in locale are not reflected to Swing components, e.g. table cells. Is there a particular procedure for that?

Comment: @drbb I add a more detailed example above. For the table cells I don't know what's not working for you. Maybe this site could help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html
Have a look on the example TableRenderDemo.java. Change the Integer values to Double values to see how it works.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I thought it was possible to alter the default behavior without using explicit NumberFormat instances in printf()/String.format(), now I see I have to use them. Regarding the JTable issue, I guess I'll have to fiddle with the Editor/Renderer of the cell, I'll look into that, thanks for the links.